# JQuery Onsubmit URL Redirect based on Radio Box Value

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect

I have been struggling for days to try and include some jquery to change the page URL, onsubmit, based on the value of a radio box (note the radio box values cannot change).

This is my HTML

```
<form id="myformid">
<input type="radio" name="selectid" value="1"><span>Google</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectid" value="2"><span>Yahoo</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectid" value="3"><span>Bing</span>
```

this is the jquery I WANT to use, but I know it is wrong...

```
$("#myformid").submit(function(){
if($("#selectid").val()==="1"){
    $(this).attr("action","http://www.google.com");   
} else { 
if($("#selectid").val()==="2"){
    $(this).attr("action","http://www.yahoo.com"); 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `#selectid` select element has same id attribute not name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

Notice that I'm getting the selected value by using `"input:radio[name ='selectid']:checked"`. Using `#` in a selector as you have looks for ID, whereas your radios are defined by `name`.

This should look for all radio inputs of name `selectid`, find the checked one, and get its value. I've also cleaned up some minor issues regarding your curly brackets.

```
$("#myformid").submit(function(){

    var checkedVal = $("input:radio[name ='selectid']:checked").val();        

    if(checkedVal === "1"){
        $(this).attr("action","http://www.google.com");   
    } else if(checkedVal === "2"){
        $(this).attr("action","http://www.yahoo.com"); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks... over 100 google searches and countless hours later. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, you were close! Just needed a few minor tweaks.